# Undefined index: $email error when i try to Login from android application

Tags: php, android, mysql

i know its qustions that already people ask.
so i try yo built Login and Registration system for android app.
when i insert data on signup activiy and register.php i dont have a problem. all record in mysql database with no problem.

but when i try to log in with user from the table, its given me error, probaly from my login php file.
this is the 2 error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: $email in C:\xampp\htdocs\android_registrer_login\login.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\android_registrer_login\login.php on line 11
This Email is not valid
```

i read post with similar problem, and i try to add isset, still dont help me to slove the problem.
also, when i try to log in with some row from mysql and run the php file from the browser its work fine!

I mean:

```
//test if success log
$email = "demoaccount@gmail.com";
$password = "123456";
/*
$email = $_POST['$email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
*/
```

this is my login php file.

```
<?php

require_once 'connect.php';

/*
test if success log
$email = "demoaccount@gmail.com";
$password = "123456";
*/
$email = $_POST['$email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];



$isVaildEmail = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if($conn){
    if($isVaildEmail === false){
        echo "This Email is not valid";
    }else{
        $sqlCheckEmail = "SELECT * FROM  users_table WHERE email LIKE '$email'";
        $emailQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCheckEmail);


        if (mysqli_num_rows($emailQuery) >0){
            $sqlLogin = "SELECT * FROM  users_table WHERE email LIKE '$email' AND  password LIKE '$password'";
            $loginQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlLogin);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($loginQuery) >0){
                echo "Login success";
            }else{
                echo "Wrong password";
            }
        }else{
            echo "This Email is not registered";
        }
    }

}else{
    echo  "Connection Error";
}
```

thanks!

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. Parameterize your query. Do you have elements in your form that match PHP variable syntax? Maybe you meant `$email = $_POST['$email'];` to be `$email = $_POST['email'];`. Same with `password`. Additionally hash your passwords, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php. Also https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php Your `like` also might get you the wrong results. A user could pass in `%` and match any record. Use `=` for equality.

Comment: dude, you right!
$email = $_POST['$email']; to be $email = $_POST['email'];

i over each peace of my code 500 times and not see it!
thanks my friend

Comment: i also change and use = and not like operator.

Comment: Just two more things to do and you'll be on a good start here. Also for future reference `Undefined index` means an array's value `$something['value']` doesn't exist.